# QR Codes How to Get link current page?

Tags: java, javascript, php, wordpress, qr-code

Hello i'm new in programming need a little help to customize QR code script and want to use on my website.

what i want is automatic get link so edited below line and replace Input Text with

```
<input id="text" type="text" value="http://www.demo.com"/><br />
```

but i when i tried on wordpress site i gives input line i don't want that line just only QR code image of current link i think need to remove and replace something in this script 
also tried to remove

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="qrcode.js"></script>
<body>
<input id="text" type="text" value="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"/><br />
<div id="qrcode" style="width:100px; height:100px; margin-top:15px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var qrcode = new QRCode(document.getElementById("qrcode"), {
width : 100,
height : 100
});
function makeCode () {      
var elText = document.getElementById("text");

if (!elText.value) {
    alert("Input a text");
    elText.focus();
    return;
}

qrcode.makeCode(elText.value);
}
makeCode();
$("#text").
on("blur", function () {
    makeCode();
}).
on("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        makeCode();
    }
});
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use QR Code WordPress plugin to insert a QR code in your blog. The qr code contains the current URL or any other text you like.

Download it from [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/qrcode-wprhe/)

**How to use it:**

1. Use the shortcode [qrcode] within your site to generate a QR Code including the URL of the current site
2. Use the fullowing short code to generate a indivdual qr code with any text content:
   [qrcode content="CONTENT" size="80" alt="ALT_TEXT" class="CLASS_NAME"]
3. Possible parameters are: alt, size, class, credit, shadow
4. If you don`t give any parameter like 'alt' or 'size', the standard parameters are:
   alt = "Scan the QR Code"
   size = 120
   class=""
   credit = true
   shadow = true

**How to install the plugin:**

1. Download the file qrcode-wprhe.zip Do not rename the file !important
2. Go to your Wordpress administrator panel at /wp-admin
3. Got to /wp-admin/plugin-install.php and upload the downloaded zip file
4. Activate the plugin through the 'Plugins' menu in WordPress
5. Use the shortcode [qrcode] within your desired posts.
6. DONE

Answer (score 0):

OK currently i'm using display:none; for input box so it resolve my problem temporary.